# Cropping image for portrait and landscape modes

Tags: android, crop, landscape-portrait

In my app user can select his own background image. The problem is, that current crop library only allows single rectangle selection. So when user selects image in portrait and rotates to landscape, image becomes inappropriately cropped. Is there a library that would at least allow to have two visible rectangles (one for portrait, another one for landscape) while selecting the image?

Answer (score 0):

Scissors
https://github.com/lyft/scissors

i am using this library to done cropping for portrait and landscape. if u use this library just sent the ViewPortRatio of CropView  for portrait or landscape cropping.

cropView.setViewportRatio(1f / 1.77f); // For Portrait

cropView.setViewportRatio(35f / 19f); // For Landscape

Comment: Does this code imply that you have two different selections, one for portrait and one for landscape or this is is all done in one go?

Comment: Yes two different selections one for potrait or one for landscape or u can define your logic use the same one for potrait or use it gaian for landscape it depends on you

Comment: So basically I already have this functionality since I have no problems using my current library in portrait and landscape separately. I'm more interested in the ability to combine these two modes to have some sort of plus sign selection rectangles, which this library doesn't seem to offer.